# Proper way of uploading an image, and then referencing it from JSP (Glassfish)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload, glassfish

I've got a servlet that uploads files. Ok, the location in which it locates them, when I point to a location "uploads", is this:

NetBeans\8.2\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1\config\uploads

I tried writing directly into domain\docroot and many other places (using a direct reference to them). It all works correctly, but then, after I upload the file, I try to redirect the request to **"message.jsp"**.

Where should I upload the file, and how should I reference it from an html or jsp? Because I'm trying to display the image, passing the image name via a session attribute, but I cannot see the image, wherever do I upload it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I got it:

The directory in which you should upload files, is in the folder where you have the projects, in my case, **Users/Documents/Netbeansprojects/Myproject/web**. I've put there the "uploads" folder, and referenced there from the FileUpload servlet.

From the html, to show an image:

```
<img src="../uploads/yourImage.jpg">
```

Now the servers are saved in that folder, and the HTML/JSP files can read them perfectly.